# Displaying messages to users through class

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with displaying errors on my login form.

My class is called "Class.auth.php" and the login works fine as does the function to direct users back if they are not logged in.

In my Auth Class file I have:

```
public $feedback_negatives = array();
```

And then later on I have the following, for if the login fails:

```
$this->feedback_negatives[] = "Login failed.";
```

This is then shown on the page by:

```
if (isset($auth)) {

    if ($auth->feedback_negatives) {
            foreach ($auth->feedback_negatives as $feedback_negative){
                    echo $feedback_negative;
                }
        }
}
```

This however doesn't seem to work. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I was previously using $_SESSION to store error messages (as quite a few answers here recommended) but this seems cleaner. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does $auth->feedback_negatives holds session array?

Comment: No, the Auth feedback simply holds the feedback message. Though it appears this either isn't being set or relayed back to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with more object oriented way, here is a good class which you can use which holds flash messages for the next request.

[Session-based Flash Messages class for PHP](https://github.com/plasticbrain/PhpFlashMessages)

So you really don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Regarding your case ($auth->feedback_negatives) when you redirect after login failure, the auth object is gonna destroy from memory so your $auth->feedback_negatives will be empty when you will try to get it after the page has been refreshed.

So what you need to do is to store a SESSION array/variable in $auth->feedback_negatives member variable and use accessor and mutator to check whether there are error messages in session array to actually get and show it on to login page. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the Session Based Flash Messages. This is just what is needed! I'm having some trouble though:

After requiring the php file, starting a session and then trying 

if ($msg->hasErrors()) {
    // There ARE errors
} else {
  // There are NOT any errors
}

Notice: Undefined variable: msg in /var/www/html/newlogin/index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on null in /var/www/html/newlogin/index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/newlogin/index.php on line 10 

I feel like I'm missing somethig obvious here

Comment: Yes, you miss to include the file in index.php 

require '/path/to/FlashMessages.php';

$msg = new \Plasticbrain\FlashMessages\FlashMessages();

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thank you. So in my class I can just call an error `$msg->error('Failed.');` or do I have to include other things?

Comment: yes, in your class just set the error $msg->error('Failed.'); and in index.php just display. $msg->display();

Answer (score 0):

As you are checking for `$auth` existance and if it does `$auth->feedback_negatives` will always exist you could simplify that code to

```
if (isset($auth)) {
    foreach ($auth->feedback_negatives as $feedback_negative){
        echo $feedback_negative;
    }
}
```

as doing a foreach over an empty array is quite legal, it just wont produce any output.

Alternatively, test the array by doing a count like this

```
if (isset($auth)) {
    if (count($auth->feedback_negatives) > 0) {
        foreach ($auth->feedback_negatives as $feedback_negative){
           echo $feedback_negative;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your second snippet and added an else {echo "None.";} - Every time I put wrong info in the form I get "None" displayed meaning that something in the checking isn't working to be either setting or relaying the errors array. Is $this->feedback_negatives[] = "Login failed."; correct to be using in my auth class?

Comment: Is this all happening in one script, or are you assuming that the class will maintain its contents across 2 seperate scripts

Comment: The login page sends the input to the auth class using $auth->login so it's the same class but different functions.